# Is there any way to add a new page to my work in Illustrator ?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs5, artboard

Is there any way to add a new page to my work in Illustrator ?

I've seen these buttons on the bottom:[image: pages]

I guess they are for the pages ?

thanks

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks like you're working with CS5, so the answer is Yes. And No. Okay, so before you go all rolled eyes and raised eyebrows, here's how it works.

AI CS5 introduced multiple art boards in a single document. These aren't really "pages" in the conventional sense, because they can be arbitrary sizes (useful when you want to create a corporate identity kit with logo, business card, letterhead, envelope and notepad all in one document). There's no automatic page numbering, or any of the things you'd associate with "pages," except for this: when you Save As a PDF, if your file has multiple artboards you'll see a page range selector at the bottom of the PDF preset dialog.

So no, AI doesn't really do pages as such, but yes, you can save a multi-page PDF from IA CS5.

Just in case it's not clear, to add a "page," select the Art Board tool (between the Chart and Slice tools) and draw out your new artboard(s).

Comment: Actually, the multiple artboard feature was available at least as early as CS3, they just didn't do a very good job with it ;) There is a 'crop area tool' which became the artbord tool. Until you hold option (IIRC) only your current artboard is visible.

Answer (score 4):

I am new to illustrator but this is how I added a new artboard in the same file:

Click on <kbd>Window > Artboards</kbd> to show the `Artboard` panel. In there, click on `new` (just as you'd do for new a layer).

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on Windows - Layers
2. Default view is layers, next to it is artboard - choose artboard
3. Click new artboard icon at the bottom (next to the dustbin icon)

You are done.

Comment: Correct answer in IMHO that the OP said 'add' rather than start

Answer (score 1):

Open Adobe Illustrator on your computer. Click `File` at the top left-hand corner of the menu bar and select `New`.

Locate the `Number of Artboards` box and change the number according to how many pages you want.